# Best Practices when using .NET Session for temporary storage?

Tags: asp.net, session, session-variables, temporary

I'm still relatively new to .NET and ASP.NET MVC, and I have had a few occasions where it would be nice to store information retrieved from the DB temporarily so it can be used on a subsequent server request from the client. I have begun using the .NET Session to store this information, keyed off of a timestamp, and then retrieve the information using the timestamp when I hit the server again.

So a basic use case:

1. User clicks 'Query' button to gather information from the system.
2. In JS, generate a timestamp of the current time, and pass this to the server with request
3. On server, gather information from DB
4. On server, use unique timestamp from client as a key into the Session to store the response object.
5. Return response object to client
6. User clicks 'Generate Report' button (will format query results into Excel doc)
7. Pass same timestamp from #2 down to server again, and use to gather query results from #4.
8. Generate report w/o additional DB hit.

This is the scheme that I have begun to use in any case where I use the Session as temporary storage. But generating a timestamp in JS isn't necessarily secure, and the whole things feels a little... unstructured. Is there an existing design pattern I can use for this, or a more streamlined/secure approach? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the purpose of the JS timestamp?

Comment: The JS timestamp is meant to be a unique value that can be used as a key into the Session variable. We could generate a random number as easily, but even that is repeatable.

Answer (score 1):

You may take a look at `TempData` which stores the data in Session.When you pull something out of `TempData` it will be removed after the Action is done executing.

So, if you put something in `TempData` in an Action, it will live in `TempData` across all other actions until its requested `TempData`from TempData again.

You can also call `TempData.Peek("key")` which will keep it in memory until you call `TempData["key"]` or `TempData.Remove("key")`

Comment: By my understanding, TempData is only good for the current request and the next one. If I store the response of the query in TempData (presumably to retrieve when they click "Generate Report") and the user decides that their next action is to Ctrl+click a link on the page instead of generating the report, I'm out of luck when they do decide to generate the report. ViewData was good only through the Ctrl+click action, and no longer contains the response object. There are lots of articles that say TempData is good for redirects and redirects only.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I'm not sure I understand you correctly as the JS timestamp step seems superfluous.
But this is what I would do.

```
public static string SessionReportKey = "Reports";
public static string ReportIDString = "ReportID";
public Dictionary<string, object> SessionReportData
{
    get
    {
        return Session[SessionReportKey] == null ? 
            new Dictionary<string, object>() : 
            (Dictionary<string, object>) Session[SessionReportKey];
    }
    set
    {
        Session[SessionReportKey] = value;
    }
}
public ActionResult PreviewReport()
{
    //retrive your data
    object reportData = GetData();

    //get identifier
    string myGUID = new GUID().ToString();

    //might only need [SessionReportData.Add(myGUID, reportData);] here
    SessionReportData = SessionReportData.Add(myGUID, reportData);

    //in your view make a hyperlink to PrintReport action with a 
    //query string of [?ReportID=<guidvalue>]
    ViewBag[ReportIDString] = myGUID;

    return View(reportData);
}


public FileContentResult PrintReport()
{
    if(SessionReportData[QueryString[ReportIDString]] == null)
    {
        //error no report in session
        return null;
    }
    return GenerateFileFromData(SessionReportData[QueryString[ReportIDString]]);
}
```